# Select, update and return selected value

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to lock rows in the same moment as it's been selected.
So I need some kind of transaction that will:

1) `SELECT * FROM changes WHERE locked=0`

2) `UPDATE changes SET locked=1`

3) `return 1st query result`

Is it possible?

Comment: Probably. What have you tried?

Comment: What do you mean by "1st query result"? You're not using an `ORDER BY` so it'll be mildly arbitrary

Comment: I mean result of ```SELECT * FROM changes WHERE locked=0```

Answer (score 0):

you can mix all queries together so you can get the final result as you want, you will need to sign the date of the change to be able to sort and filtering for the last change:

transact SQL:

```
string sql = "update changes set locked = 1, changed_date = getdate() where locked = 0;select top 1 * from changes order by changed_date desc;";
DataTable tbl = dal.fillAdapter();
```

or call Stored Procedure holding the same queries, you can execute scalar to check if any row affected because the update and only if changes happens you will query for the last changes, in other words endless combinations to solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have clarified, transactions will be your best bet ([docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html)).

```
START TRANSACTION;
/* Select the records to be changed */
SELECT * FROM changes WHERE locked=0;
/* Update records to set those that are not locked to locked */ 
UPDATE changes SET locked=1 WHERE locked = 0;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: sorry, context switching :) I'm not getting result of ```SELECT * FROM changes WHERE locked=0;``` if I run the whole query

Comment: Are you sure there are values that are not locked?